# How to communicate persistent content to developer working on consuming classes

Tags: c#

Let's say we have a business object, let's call it a `Foo`, which contains an ordered list of `Bar`s.  We pass this `Foo` around as XML.

We have a class which deserializes a `Foo` XML node (`FooXMLDeserializer`) which itself uses a class which deserializes the child `Bar` XML nodes (`BarXMLDeserializer`).

Now, I'm adding some functionality to the `BarXMLDeserializer` that maintains some state such that if `FooXMLDeserializer` is called on two separate `Foo` nodes without reseting the `BarXMLDeserializer`'s state, the results may be invalid.  `BarXMLDeserializer` does not know when it has processed the final `Bar` in a `Foo`.

Is there some way that I can design the `BarXMLDeserializer` class to communicate to developers working on consuming classes that it has state and must be reset for each `Foo`?

**Further info:**

- My change solves a minor enough problem in our code that I won't be able to convince my manager to let me spend X days redesigning the whole system to nicely handle this case.
- If it matters, `BarXMLDeserializer` keeps is state in a `BarStateTracker` class which is internal to it.
- Programming in C#, but looking for a more general solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expose your serializer only as a static method:

```
// no public constructor, etc
var deserializer = BarXMLDeserializer.CreateNew();
```

Then, when you have finished deserializing data, mark a field in your object. If the field is set, throw an exception if the same instance is used to deserialize more data when the deserialize method is called.

```
if(IsInstanceExhausted)
   throw new InvalidOperationException("You must use a fresh instance.");
```

They'll figure it out after their first exception. In addition, mark your class as IDisposable so that code naturally uses using statements:

```
using(var deserializer = BarXMLDeserializer.CreateNew())
{
}
```

The list goes on of additional ways. **ALTERNATIVELY**, you could simply design your Deserializer to clear it's state or reset after a deserialization attempt, or to clear the state at the beginning of a deserialization attempt.